# custom data type for databasechangeloglock

Tags: liquibase

I have a customer that mandates creating tables by himself. This forces me to also allow the customer to define the 2 liquibase tables. That's fine as liquibase allows setting the table names.

I have a problem with the databasechangeloglock table. Turns out the customer only supports these data types:

```
INTEGER
NUMBER
VARCHAR
FLOAT
DATE
```

Boolean is not there so I am having trouble with the `lock` field.

I tried defining the table with `VARCHAR (5)`.

That worked for INSERT but for the UPDATE. the Where clause: `LOCK = FALSE` fails on:
`operator does not exist: character varying = boolean`

According to this page, I thought it should have uset Int but seems not. https://www.liquibase.org/documentation/databasechangeloglock_table.html

Is there anyway to instruct liquibase to use another data type?

Answer (score 0):

Liquibase should create the type for the `locked` column based on the underlying database.

Chekout this class [CreateDatabaseChangeLogLockTableGenerator](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/sqlgenerator/core/CreateDatabaseChangeLogLockTableGenerator.java) and the `generateSql` method.

It will use [BooleanType](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/datatype/core/BooleanType.java) to find the type for the `locked` column. 
For some of the DBs (Derby and DB2) it looks for a method `supportsBooleanDataType()`.

So maybe you can overwrite this by inheriting from the right class for your db in [database/core](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/tree/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/database/core). And then only supply the `supportsBooleanDataType()` and return `false`.

There should be way to include your own version of a Database class so you can change behaviour.